# iphone UIProgressBar

Tags: iphone, uiprogressview

I am having two values targetValue and receivedValue . Now I want to show the status on Progress bar. Means if targetValue is 1000 and receivedValue is 500 then progress bar should display 50% of filled area.

So I want to know that is there any easy way to do so... or I have to calculate the values any have to set with `myProgressBar.progress = value` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use below

```
myProgressBar.progress = receivedValue /targetValue ;
```

The value of `receivedValue /targetValue` will fall in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 ;

Comment: @maulik : Use receivedValue and targetValue as float variable OR float t = (float)receivedValue /(float)targetValue;

Comment: It's perfect I used it long back but I forgot thank you man. You remembered me the good solution+1

Answer (score 2):

ofcorse you have to calculate value and pass it.

```
myProgressBar.progress = value
```

Comment: ok ! i thought there would be some inbuilt function to set max value for progress bar and based on current value its display filled area... thanks for reply

Comment: just convert ur value in 0-100 by calculating percentage. that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I recommend:

```
-(void)UpdateProgressbar:(NSNumber*)currentOperationNumer TotalOperationNumber:(NSNumber*)n
{       
    NSLog(@" operation : %i", currentOperationNumer);
    NSLog(@" total : %i", n);       

    NSString *inStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", n];
    NSLog(@"%@", inStr);

    NSString *Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", currentOperationNumer];
    NSLog(@"%@", Str);
    if (currentOperationNumer <= n) {           
        [downloadBar setProgress:([Str intValue]/[inStr floatValue])];
        NSLog(@"progress !");           
    }
    else {
        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
    }    
}
```